# Linking an existing folder to a solution in Visual C# Express

Tags: c#

Note that these are my first steps in the world of C# so I may be asking something really basic here, however neither Google nor Visual C# Express Help helped me so I'm forced to ask this here.

I have a set of `.cs` files in a folder (and its subfolders) I have checked out from SVN repository using TortoiseSVN. I would like to see those files with the same folder structure in Visual C# Express 2008 I'm running. However, I can't find the correct import or dynamic linking wizard, and drag'n'drop apparently clones the files to the solution instead of just linking them.

So, what am I missing, coming from the Java world and being an Eclipse user I've become used to this kind of functionality, but with VC#E I feel stumped already and I haven't even managed to open a single source file.

The reason for this setup is that we have a collaborative project with a couple of friends and not every one of us uses VC#E, in fact not all of us even use Windows either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

- Create an empty C# project, locating the .csproj file in the folder in which the files (and sub folders) are located
- Open the Solution Explorer (View -> Solution Explorer)
- In the Solution Explorer, click the tool button "Show All Files". Now you should see the code files in the tree view
- Select all the code files (and sub folders), right-click and select "Include in project"

Done.

Comment: This worked after a bit of fiddling. Awfully unintuitive way to do this but whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your .csproj file to a folder above your directory structure. There are other possibilities but they are generally for other use cases and quite a pain for what you're trying to do.